# Find average by group over a time period and retrieve last date for same period

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

Below is a reproducible data table with four columns:

1. Date
2. category
3. value1
4. value2

As the title suggests, I'd like to calculate average values from **value1** and **value2** per category, and keep the last observed date for those categories in the resulting dataframe.

**Here's the input:**

```
# Libraries
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# Reproducible data table
set.seed(1234)
date <- seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 10)
category <- (c('A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C','C', 'C'))
value1 <- sample(seq(from = 91, to = 100, by = 1))
value2 <- sample(seq(from = 51, to = 60, by = 1))
dt <- data.table(date, category, value1, value2)
print(dt)

          date category value1 value2
 1: 2017-01-01        A     92     57
 2: 2017-02-01        A     96     55
 3: 2017-03-01        B     95     53
 4: 2017-04-01        B     98     60
 5: 2017-05-01        C     99     52
 6: 2017-06-01        C     94     59
 7: 2017-07-01        C     91     56
 8: 2017-08-01        C     97     51
 9: 2017-09-01        C    100     58
10: 2017-10-01        C     93     54
```

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
dt2 <- dt %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
print(dt2)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  category       date   value1 value2
     <chr>     <date>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1        A 2017-01-16 94.00000   56.0
2        B 2017-03-16 96.50000   56.5
3        C 2017-07-16 95.66667   55.0
```

**And here is the desired output:**

```
  category       date   value1 value2
1        A 2017-02-01 94.00000   56.0
2        B 2017-04-01 96.50000   56.5
3        C 2017-10-01 95.66667   55.0
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the `data.table` approach. We can perform the calculations in `.()` with the `j` argument, and set the grouping in the `by` argument.

```
dt[, .(date = last(date), value1 = mean(value1), value2 = mean(value2)), by = category]
```

Here is a more efficient way developed by Frank as a comment on this post. This approach only needs to write the `mean` function once, using `.SD` and `.SDcols` to specify which columns to be summarised in mean.

```
dt[, c(.(date = last(date)), lapply(.SD, mean)), by = category, .SDcols = value1:value2]
```

And if you want to use `dplyr`, you can use Z.Lin's approach. However, if there are lots of value columns, such as `value1` to `value10`, you can do the following.

```
dt %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(if_else(is.numeric(.), mean(.), last(.))))
```

This code will only calculate mean if the columns are numeric, otherwise, it will report the last row of a group.

One final reminder, `summarise_each` has been deprecated. Please use `summarise_all`, `summarise_if`, or `summarise_at`.

Comment: @Frank Good point. I don't know the equivalent of `dplyr`'s `sumarise_all`, `summarise_if`, or `summarise_at` in `data.table`.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for sharing your solution and reporting the bug. `if_else` is necessary here because `ifelse` will coerce the date column to be numeric.

Comment: @Frank I noticed that if I changed your code from `by = date` to `by = category`, this seems to lead to the desired output without warnings or error messages. With your permission, I would like to add your solution to my post as an addition.

Comment: also can use `max(date)`, which is the same as `last(date)`

Comment: `dt %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(if_else(is.numeric(.), mean(.), last(.))))` is a piece of pure R beauty. I my humble opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
dt %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(date = max(date),
            value1 = mean(value1),
            value2 = mean(value2)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  category       date   value1 value2
     <chr>     <date>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1        A 2017-02-01 94.00000   56.0
2        B 2017-04-01 96.50000   56.5
3        C 2017-10-01 95.66667   55.0
```

Comment: Nice solution. I develop a similar approach using `summarise_all` in case the OP has lots of columns need to be summarised in mean.