# Summarise numeric columns, return last value of non-numeric

Tags: r, dplyr

It's not uncommon to want to summarise numeric columns of a dataframe or tibble, while doing something else to non-numeric columns.

There is a nice trick for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45802176/302378), but it seems to fail for character columns.

First, here it is working, returning the mean of the numeric columns and the value of the first row of the other columns

```
set.seed(1234)
category <- (c('A','A','E','E','B','B','C'))
date <- seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 7)
value1 <- sample(seq(from = 91, to = 97, by = 1))
dt <- data.frame(category, date, value1)
dt<- as_tibble(dt)
#works
dt2<- dt %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(if_else(is.numeric(.), mean(.), last(.))))
print(dt2)
```

Note that because the date column is non-numeric, it returns the value in the last row instead of the mean:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  category date       value1
  <fct>    <date>      <dbl>
1 A        2017-02-01   92.5
2 B        2017-06-01   93.5
3 C        2017-07-01   97  
4 E        2017-04-01   94.5
```

However, it fails when one of the columns is chr

```
marsupial <-c("quoll","phascogale",'triok','opossum','antechinus','bandicoot','Fat-tailed dunnart')
dt$marsupial <- marsupial
dt3<- dt %>% #doesn't work
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(if_else(is.numeric(.), mean(.), last(.))))
print(dt3)
```

Giving these errors:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `false` must be type double, not character.
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(marsupial) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I assume the `'false' must be type double` refers to the marsupial column resulting in attempt to evaluate `last`. If so, why must it be double, and is there another way? I wouldn't expect this from a conventional if/else conditional.

Comment: `summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)`

Comment: If you want to keep the current structure, the issue is because `dplyr::if_else` is strict about types. `ifelse` or `if ... else ...` work. The former will drop the date attributes, though, which is annoying, so `if (is.numeric(.)) mean(.) else last(.)` is probably best.

Comment: @alistaire With `if (is.numeric(.)) mean(.) else last(.)` I get this error: `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Column "date" must be length 1 (a summary value), not 7` but maybe I misunderstood how to use it, and yes `ifelse` drops the date attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2021, this is the current syntax:

```r
dt %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(across(is.numeric, mean),
            across(where(~ !is.numeric(.)), last))
```

Answer (score 2):

ifelse seems to be the problem so i have created a function.  I have updated my answer. i have tested it on the dates attributes and it seems to work on the list as well. I hope it'll solve your problem:

```
dt %>% group_by(category) %>%
  summarise_all(function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x)){
    return(mean(x))
  }else{
    nth(x,-1)
  }
}
)
```

Comment: That works, except, as @alistaire said, it drops the date attributes. (And it also doesn't work for columns that are lists, but I didn't ask for a solution that would handle that).

Comment: I have updated my answer. i have tested it on the dates attributes and it seems to work on the list as well. I hope it'll solve your problem.

Comment: Great thanks, that works for the dates! It doesn't work on the list columns I have in another dataframe, for which I get `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Column "listColumn" must be length 1 (a summary value), not 16` but that isn't part of the original question; I'd have to make a new one for that.